# Java Swing Slider Not Popping Up Issue

Tags: java, swing

```
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main{
  public static void main(String [] args){
    
    JFrame j = new JFrame("How Happy Are You?");
    j.setSize(300,200);
    j.setVisible(true);
    j.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    JSlider s = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 10, 5);
    s.setMajorTickSpacing(5);
    s.setMinorTickSpacing(1);    
    s.setPaintTicks(true);
    s.setPaintLabels(true);
    j.add(s);

    JLabel label = new JLabel("Current Rating: " + s.getValue());
    j.add(label);

    s.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener()
    {
      public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e){
        label.setText("Current Rating: " + s.getValue());
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Hi, I'm using repl.it for Java Swing and with this code only the frame pops up but the slider itself doesn't show at all! Please help me! How do I fix this code?

Comment: For all the invocations of `setVisible(true)` I see: does the `JLabel` show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first add the slider and all other components before making to frame visible.

Just move

```
j.setVisible(true);
```

down a few lines after adding all components.